# How can you take screenshots of each step and include a page type?

Tags: ruby, jenkins, cucumber, watir

I created project that goes to 7 or so different pages on my website (home page, product pages, etc.) and I want to take a screenshot of the page after each step. I want the name of the saved screenshot to include the type of page I'm on, which I have set in a variable on the step. I added this to my hooks.rb file, but I don't know how to include the type. Can someone let me know the best way of going about this?

```
AfterStep do |scenario|
  screenshot = "#{scenario.name}.png"
  @browser.driver.save_screenshot screenshot
  embed screenshot, 'image/png'
end
```

Comment: If you already have the type of page in a variable, can you not just include it in the String that is the screenshot name?

Answer (score 0):

to name it something like scenarioName_image_png.png you would use:

```
screenshot = "#{scenario.name}"
@browser.driver.save_screenshot screenshot
embed("#{screenshot}_image_png.png")
```

for something like image_png_scenarioName.png change the last line to:

```
embed("image_png_#{screenshot}.png)
```